# Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Recently I have been having issue with some strange issue in typescript.
I'm usually developing the app on linux (manjaro), but when I tried the app on windows 10, I get this:

`Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'never'. ts(2322)`

which happens in code (in components `UserForm` and `LoginForm`):

```
<div className="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style={{ width: 320 }} onClick={handleFormOnClick}>
  {authenticated ? <UserForm /> : <LoginForm />}
</div>
```

The problem I have with this type error is not only that the error doesn't make sense to me, as both components are exported like many other components in my app are, but also the fact that on linux, I don't have any error or warning in the entire file.

Both windows and linux version are the same version (pulled from git).
Typescript version is 4.4.4 for both of them.

Both components are classes extending `React.PureComponent` exported as
`compose(withConnect)(LoginForm)` (I also tried to just use `withConnect(LoginForm)` with no luck)
I even tried to recast them as `JSX.Element` (`(<UserForm />) as JSX.Element`)

I have tried to run the code on 2 separate machines with windows 10 and both are having this error. Am I missing something? Why does it work on linux if there is something wrong with it?

Node version: 16.13.0

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must 
include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful 
to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can you check typescript versions on both computers? also include other variables or state what you have used in that line

Comment: Both machines have node 16.13.0 and typescript 4.4.4. The only variable on that line is `authenticated:boolean` which by default is false